# RecyclerView click listener not triggered on row click

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

**Edit**
It seems like my @Override for onMentorClick(Mentor mentor) is never being accessed.

I have a recycler view that shows a list of people. 
I need to be able to click on one of the people in the list and have a new activity open.

in my adapter, I have the following code:

```
private OnMentorClickListener listener;

public interface OnMentorClickListener {
        void onMentorClick(Mentor mentor);
    }

public void setOnMentorClickListener(OnMentorClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

in my activity, I have the following code:

```
mentorAdapter.setOnMentorClickListener(new MentorAdapter.OnMentorClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMentorClick(Mentor mentor) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MentorActivity.this, MentorAddEditActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_ID, mentor.getMentor_id());
                intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_NAME, mentor.getMentor_name());
                intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_PHONE, mentor.getMentor_phone());
                intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_EMAIL, mentor.getMentor_email());

                startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_MENTOR_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

I have implemented listeners for other portions of my app the exact same way and they all work. 
I've scoured my code and this setup seems to be identical to other sections of code.

I get no errors, but when I'm on my "Mentors" page and have all the mentors listed out, nothing happens when I click on one. 
No errors, no crashes, no nothing.

I've also tried to just implement the OnMentorClickListener strait into the Activity class like the following:

```
public class MentorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MentorAdapter.OnMentorClickListener
```

and overriding outside of OnCreate:

```
@Override
    public void onMentorClick(Mentor mentor) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MentorActivity.this, MentorAddEditActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_ID, mentor.getMentor_id());
        intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_NAME, mentor.getMentor_name());
        intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_PHONE, mentor.getMentor_phone());
        intent.putExtra(MentorAddEditActivity.EXTRA_MENTOR_EMAIL, mentor.getMentor_email());

        startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_MENTOR_REQUEST);
    }
```

This does not work either.

Any thoughts on my I can't actually click the mentor in the RecyclerView?

Entire MentorAdapter for clarification.  This is as identical as possible to all of my other adapters with variable names changed for Mentor.

```
public class MentorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MentorAdapter.MentorHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = AppRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    private OnMentorClickListener listener;


    private List<Mentor> mentorList = new ArrayList<>();


    class MentorHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView textViewMentorName;
        private TextView textViewMentorPhone;
        private TextView textViewMentorEmail;


        MentorHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewMentorName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mentor_name);
            textViewMentorPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mentor_phone);
            textViewMentorEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mentor_email);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(listener!=null&&position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onMentorClick(mentorList.get(position));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MentorHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mentor_item, parent, false);
        return new MentorHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MentorHolder holder, int position) {
        Mentor currentMentor = mentorList.get(position);
        holder.textViewMentorName.setText(currentMentor.getMentor_name());
        holder.textViewMentorEmail.setText(currentMentor.getMentor_email());
        holder.textViewMentorPhone.setText(currentMentor.getMentor_phone());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mentorList.size();
    }

    public void setMentorList(List<Mentor> mentors){
        this.mentorList = mentors;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Mentor getMentorAt(int position){return mentorList.get(position);}

    public interface OnMentorClickListener {
        void onMentorClick(Mentor mentor);
    }

    public void setOnMentorClickListener(OnMentorClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you add `setOnMentorClickListener (OnMentorClickListener listener)`  inside your Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that in my mentor_item.xml file used to create the layout for the Mentor RecyclerView, I had created an  across the entire card on the top layer that I wasn't doing anything with.

Once I removed that ImageButton from the xml file, the clicks were being registered and everything worked as intended.

Thank you for everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding `onMentorClick` your activity should implement `OnMentorClickListener` interface, then on your adapter you should set the activity as your listener with:

```
mentorAdapter.setOnMentorClickListener(this)
```

In your code, you're using a new click listener (not the activity)

```java
mentorAdapter.setOnMentorClickListener(new MentorAdapter.OnMentorClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMentorClick(Mentor mentor) {

            }

});
```

In addition, you should fire your `onMentorClick` on the user click in your adapter implementation, preferably in the `onCreateViewHolder` method:

```
public YourAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    ViewHolder holder = ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.your_layout,
            parent,
            false
        ))

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onMentorClick(mentor)
    }

    return holder ;
}
```

Comment: I updated my post with the entire adapter for Mentor.  This is the exact same method I've used for all of my other adapter/activity combos in my project and it works great.
I use "mentorAdapter.setOnMentorClickListener(new MentorAdapter.OnMentorClickListener()" everywhere I have a listener like this and it works everywhere but here.

Answer (score 0):

In some place you need a call to these Callback, something like this:

```
profileView.setOnClickListener(new ....
     listener.onMentorListener(mentor);
)
```

Do you have this implementation in your Adapter?

Comment: Yes I do. I have updated my question with my full adapter.